# DXA - Resolving Publication mapping incorrectly when having multiple websites

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We have 2 websites (brands) with different domains.

In Topology, the 2 websites are configured with base urls as : *http://domain1* and *http://domain2*
And mapping for UK publication exists only in domain1

```
PublicationId       : tcm:0-307-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Purpose-Live
WebApplicationId    : DOMAIN1_LIVE_WEBSITE_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /uk
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://domain1/uk
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : Live_Mapping_307
```

But when I try to get Publication for domain2 in Content service using GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport (via Postman) - It gets resolved to 307. This should not return any mapping.

```
http://localhost:8481/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://domain2/uk')
```

Is there any way to configure Content service (or Discovery) to do an exact match of Website + WebApplication + Mapping to resolve PublicationMapping ?

Get-TtmWebsite cmdlet output:

```
BaseUrls             : {http://domain1}
CdEnvironmentId      : Live
EnvironmentPurpose   : Purpose-Live
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : DOMAIN1_LIVE_WEBSITE
ExtensionProperties  : {}


BaseUrls             : {http://domain2}
CdEnvironmentId      : Live
EnvironmentPurpose   : Purpose-Live
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : DOMAIN2_LIVE_WEBSITE
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Get-TtmMapping output:

```
CmEnvironmentId     : CME
PublicationId       : tcm:0-307-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Purpose-Live
WebApplicationId    : DOMAIN1_LIVE_WEBSITE_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /uk
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://domain1/uk
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : Live_Mapping_307


CmEnvironmentId     : CME
PublicationId       : tcm:0-349-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Purpose-Live
WebApplicationId    : DOMAIN2_LIVE_WEBSITE_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /us
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://domain2/us
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : Domain2_Live_Mapping_307
ExtensionProperties : {}
```

We also have similar mappings for both domain1 and domain2 (like /uk in domain1 and /uk/en in domain2), but there are few which are specific to domain1 only (for example: /global, or /worldwide) which do not exist for domain2.

But when requesting for PublicationMapping, like this
*http://localhost:8481/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://domain2/global')* - we get response of mapping that exist for domain1.

Tridion- 8.5
DXA - 2.0 Java

Comment: Can you share your output of Get-TtmWebsite cmdlets?

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan, I have updated the question with Get-TtmWebsite cmdlet output.

Comment: Also Get-TtmMapping output?

Comment: regarding "/uk in domain1 and /uk/en in domain2" domain2 only has mapping /us right? where is the mapping /uk/en? can you also share the Get-TtmWebApplication cmdlet to see the contextual

Comment: Your TTM configuration looks fine and the resolving behavior you report sounds like a defect in Content Delivery. I recommend to contact SDL Customer Support for this

Comment: @Velmurugan TtmWebApplication has only RootWebApplication for 2 websites. 

domain1 and domain2 has a lot of mappings (example, /uk, /us, /nl, etc.) 
/uk/en exists only in domain2.. (in domain1 we have /uk - without language code)

But the proble here is that mapping is resolved even if we don't have it in domain2, example: /global - which exists in domain1 only.

Comment: @RickPannekoek Thanks Rick, i will raise a request with SDL support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by SDL in following Hotfix: CD_8.5.0.21995

> CRQ-21932 - DXA - Resolving Publication mapping incorrectly when
> having multiple websites

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use context URLs instead on relative URLs when you setup topology?

I have faced a similar issue with 8.5 since one of the content delivery jars sorts the first hit from the mappings based on the pattern search. I used context URLs to resolve the issue. SDL may have a hotfix now.

Comment: What's a "context URL"?